# Does dismissing a flag as valid affect the post the flag is attached to?

Tags: support, flags, moderator-abilities

Moderators can choose between dismissing flags as valid or invalid. I understand the choice changes the weight of the users' flag in the future, but I wonder if flagging as valid will change anything to the relevant post.

For example, non-3kers can flag questions with any valid close reason. Does dismissing a flag as valid apply my super-close-vote as suggested by the flagger?

Comment: You guys need a sandbox SE. Although that would present a problem to anyone who wanted to make an SE site about sandboxes....

Comment: @Popular I guess that's what per-site metas really are about!

Answer (score 4):

> non-3kers can flag questions with common close reasons. Does dismissing a flag as valid apply my super-close-vote with that close reason?

No, it won't.

> but I wonder if flagging as valid will change anything to the relevant post.

Not to the post in question.